# Как с помощью регулярных выражений вытащить данные заключенные между `<>`?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть строка вида:

```
23 35 ghfjghfj и т.д <test1> рандомные данные <test2> рандомные данные <test3>
```

как с помощью регулярных выражений вытащить данные заключенные между `<>`. И допустим первые 2 `<>` пропустить и вытащить `<test3>`?

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример строки и результат который вы хотите получить после выборки.

Comment: строка `"23 35 ghfjghfj"` не содержит символов `"<>"`, поэтому приведите в вопросе пример исходной строки и то что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: `test3` всегда в конце? Количество элементов в угловых скобках всегда равно трём? Другие "рандомные данные" могут содержать угловые скобки? Данные в угловых скобках могут содержать пробелы, знаки табуляции, символы переноса строки?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import re

text = "23 35 ghfjghfj и т.д <test1> рандомные данные <test2> рандомные данные <test3>"
items = re.findall('<(.+?)>', text)
print(items)      # ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
print(items[-1])  # 'test3'
```

Или так:

```
match = re.search('.+>.+<(.+?)>', text)
print(match.group(1))  # 'test3'
```